# DS3231 not keeping time when Arduino is turned off

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

I am trying to make an LED clock using an DS3231 to keep track of time, but for some reason, it's not keeping time when the Arduino is turned off.

I tried to disconnect the clock from a power source for 5 minutes, and when I powered it back on, the clock picks up the time it was displaying before powering off. I thought the battery I was using at first ran out, and so I replaced it with a new one, but the issue persists. Then I read that it could be that I am using the non-rechargeable one, and to fix this, I removed some resistors and diodes to turn off the charging function, but that also didn't fix the issue. At this point, I'm not sure if this is more on hardware or software issue that the clock is not keeping count of time when Arduino is turned off. It could be that the module I bought was the cheap knockoff, which doesn't function like it should, so I ordered a better one.

I'll the provide the snippet of codes I used:

```cpp
#include <RTClib.h>
#include <Wire.h>

RTC_3231 rtc;

int hoursNow;
int minutesNow;
int secondsNow;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.begin();
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
//  rtc.adjust(DateTime(2023, 6, 31, 14, 21, 0));
}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  hoursNow = now.hour();
  minutesNow = now.minute();
  secondsNow = now.second();
  Serial.print(hoursNow);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(minutesNow);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(secondsNow);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something in the code that is causing it not to do what I want it to do, but I've looked online, and most were pretty similar to the code I have.

Answer (score 3):

```
rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
```

You have this line in setup that sets the date and time to the date and time that the code was compiled.  That's fine to set it once, but that time never changes.  It's the time that it was when you compiled the code.  So every time it runs, you are setting the time back to this.  The RTC keeps the time running while the Arduino is off, but as soon as it's turned on your code sets it back to what it was before.

If you remove that line, then things will work the way you want.  You might need to load a sketch once with a line like this to set the time, run it once, then load a new sketch without that line.  Or include a routine in your code to allow a user to set the time.

Comment: How would that work? Should I use a conditional statement? I've tried commenting out that particular line just as you suggested, and sure enough, the rtc is keeping real time. However, without that line, it won't update the time to match my current time.

Comment: I said it in my answer.  Load a sketch that allows you to set the time.  Run it ONCE.  Now the time is set.  Then load a NEW sketch that doesn't set the time and the RTC will still have the right time that was set by the sketch before.